# Is there any way to make out if row is already updated postgres:golang

Tags: postgresql, go

I am using postgres as my database and https://github.com/lib/pq as library.
I am updating a record using prepared statement

```
stmt, _:= db.Prepare("UPDATE account set status='deleted' where id= $1")   
defer stmt.Close()
result, _:= stmt.Exec(accountId)
success, _:= result.RowsAffected()
```

And I noticed that the even if the row is already updated with the status=deleted update query always returns success=1. Is there any way we can differentiate between already updated row and not yet updated row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes just check in the where if the row needs updating.

```
UPDATE account SET status='deleted' 
  WHERE id= $1 AND status <> 'deleted'
```